# FullCalendar - Calendar not showing (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a student who is trying to develop a scheduler for a certain project, but I cannot seem to get FullCalendar to work on my page. I tried using the page the guide helps you create, but that did not work, so now I am trying to use one of the demo pages provided in the FullCalendar folder that I downloaded.
I previously used VS 2015, but now switched over to VS 2017 Community but that didn't help either.
My page:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Schedule";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='~/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='~/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='~/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='~/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='~/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-04-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2017-04-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2017-04-07',
                    end: '2017-04-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-04-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-04-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2017-04-11',
                    end: '2017-04-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2017-04-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2017-04-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2017-04-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2017-04-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2017-04-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2017-04-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2017-04-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2017-04-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Calendar</h2>
<div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance to any helpers!

EDIT (April 26th):
I pressed F12 as suggested and saw that the console logs an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function".
I looked at some other posts that mentioned this issue but I could find no second mention of jquery and made sure the order of references was correct, which were the mentioned solutions in those situations.
Is there anything else that can be causing this?

EDIT (April 27th):
All files seem to be loading:
[Loaded files in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV70X.png)

Comment: Check the Network(F12 on Chrome) tab and check if all the css and js files are being loaded correctly.

Comment: When you say "It doesnt work" what do you mean? do you see an error? blank page? What is F12 telling you?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan The page is blank. I tried F12 and it says: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function"  
Working on looking that up now, thank you for the tip!

Comment: View the page source, and look where your scripts are being included. It sounds like you're not loading the Full Calendar JavaScript file. Check the link in the `<script>` tags, and try to open the file. Perhaps you have a typo in the path. As Hackerman said, open the Network tab, and refresh. See if there are any files that aren't being downloaded.

Comment: @krillgar The files seem to be loading, including fullcalendar.js. I checked all the script tags and all of them seem to be pointing at the right places (I used auto completion to avoid typos). The files that they point to also do not seem to be corrupted. Is there perhaps a chance that it does not like the fact that they are in the wwwroot folder instead of a folder in the project itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the layout page is calling the jquery file again, see this picture.[image]

Try to remove one of them and make sure the jquery file is being called before the fullcalendar.js

Comment: I went through the entire page checking for a second reference several times but then realized that it could be in the layout too, which turned out to be the case. I deleted the second reference and now it works!  
Many thanks to all the helpers!